# mac parallels win10 expanded to take entire drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, mac, disk-space, parallels

I am running win10 via parallels on mac air 256Gb SSD with the drive split 50/50 for MacOS and Win10. from mac disk utility I see the entire 100+ Gigs being used.

In trying to clean up some space, I went into Windows to remove junk but there was little wasted space. then I noticed at most only 45Gb are used.

where is the rest of the 50 Gb going and how do I trim windows footprint?

Comment: Is this a Bootcamp instance you also launch via Parallels or just a Parallels "hard-drive" that is consuming space on your native macOS drive?  I assume the latter, but want to confirm.

Comment: its a boot camp instance.

Answer (score 0):

First, back-up the Bootcamp instance using a tool like [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/).  If you're a heavy Bootcamp Windows user, it's well worth the money.  Put that clone on an external disk as you're probably pretty low.  Remember to shutdown the Windows instance and Parallels before you do the clone.  With this, the worst case is that you can delete and recreate the Bootcamp partition and restore the Winclone clone to it.

Next, boot into Windows via Bootcamp.  Download and install [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) and launch.

Select "Move/Resize Partition," set the new size you want.  Select the "Using Enhanced Data Protecting Mode" checkbox and click OK.

Once complete, boot back into macOS and use Disk Utility to recapture the old NTFS space you just freed up.

Resizing partitions can be harrowing, but I did this process once a couple of years ago before I switched to VMWare and it worked fine.  Google "reducing Bootcamp partition" for a more detailed step by step guide.  When in doubt, back up!